# Hindu New Year ( Chaitra Shukla Paksh Pratipada )

Tags: vedas, calendar, navrathri

Many Scholars have told Hindu New Year is on Chaitra Shukla Pratipada .

But my question is Chaitra Month's 1st day will be Krishna Pratipada .

So why Shukla Pratipada is celebrated as New Year and not Krishna Pratipada ??

Please tell

Comment: New year means new creation, Shukla is the ascending creative phase from no moon to full moon while Krishna is its opposite and the descending phase of Moon like in a wave.

Comment: It's not necessary that Krishna Paksha Pritipada is 1st day..there are 2 types of calendar Purnimanta and Amanta..in Amanta, Shukla Paksha Pritipada would be 1st day of Chaitra..and based on calendar types, Hindus celebrated many new years like Marathi, Asami, Tamil etc new year..

Answer (score 3):

There are two traditions, one is called Amāvasyāṃta (अमावस्यांत) and second is Pūrṇimāṃta​ (पूर्णिमांत​). Amāvasyāṃta stands for month ends on Amāvasyā (i.e at no moon) whereas Pūrṇimāṃta​ stands for month ends on Pūrṇimā (i.e at full moon).

Amāvasyāṃta is followed in some states e.g Gujarat, Maharashtra, Tamilnadu etc. and Pūrṇimāṃta​ is followed in some states e.g Orissa, Uttara Pradesha etc. You can take a look at [drikpanchang](https://www.drikpanchang.com/faq/faq-ans8.html):

> [image]

So, **according to Amāvasyāṃta tradition, 1st day is Shukla Pratipada and according to Pūrṇimāṃta​, it is Shukla Pratipada.**

Read [a section from a book on Gupta polity](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KP_DTtd6kJEC&pg=PA24&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) for more information on the origin of Amāvasyāṃta and Pūrṇimāṃta​ traditions.

Comment: @Pandya so wheh new year should be celebrated chaitra shukla Pratipada or Chaitra's 1st day ( Krishna Pratipada) according to purimanta traditions?

Comment: @RanaPriyanshuSinh According to Purnimanta, Krishna Pratipara is 1st day

Comment: @Pandya but people tell we should celebrate chaitra shukla Pratipada as new year as brahma ji made this world on this day , Shri Ram coronation on this day , even Yudhisthir ji was coordinated on this day . So we should celebrate this day . Even in Uttar Pradesh where Purnimanta is followed CM Yogi Adityanath wished Happy New Year on shukla Pratipada. So which one is more reliable according to hindu scriptures? Pls tell