# Hindu New Year ( Chaitra Month )

Tags: vedas, vishnu, brahma, calendar, panchang

As we know that there are 2 types of Hindu calendar.

1.Purnimanta    2. Amanta

According to Purnimanta Holi is New Year i.e. Chaitra Krishna Pratipada 
but according to Amanta Chaitra Shukla Pratipada is New Year.

So my question :

1. In these 2 different new year days which one is more accurate and reliable according to ancient hindu scriptures?
2. Is it True that on Chaitra Shukla Pratipada brahma ji made this world so we should celebrate this as new year?

Thank You.

Comment: You have already raised the same question earlier (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37772/3869).  What is the purpose of posting the same question?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv  I didn't get a satisfactory answer which I wanted .

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Tell me did brahma ji create the world on shukla Pratipada